# Sometimes receive a run-time error in a code which copies ranges from excel sheet to powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I built the following code:

```
Sub Metrics()    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim pptapp As Object
    Dim wholeppt As Object
    Dim sld As Object
    Dim rng As Object
    Dim shp As Object
    Dim x As Integer

    Set pptapp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
    Set wholeppt = pptapp.ActivePresentation
    Set sld = wholeppt.Slides

    pptapp.Activate

    Set Rev = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CIS Story").Range("E1:F3")
    Set GC = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CIS Story").Range("E4:F6")
    Set GM = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CIS Story").Range("E7:F9")
    Set RPE = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CIS Story").Range("E10:F12")
    Set SPE = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CIS Story").Range("E13:F15")
    Set DDC = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CIS Story").Range("K1:L3")
    Set OPAS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CIS Story").Range("E16:F18")
    Set BHC = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CIS Story").Range("K4:L6")
    Set A = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CIS Story").Range("K10:L12")
    Set TTP = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CIS Story").Range("K13:L15")
    Set SU = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CIS Story").Range("K7:L9")

    pptapp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide 12

    Rev.Copy

    Set rng = sld(12).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPaste)

    Set shp = rng(1)

         shp.Left = 0
         shp.Top = 65
         shp.Height = 60
         shp.Width = 125
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    pptapp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide 13

    GC.Copy

    Set rng = sld(13).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPaste)

    Set shp = rng(1)

       shp.Left = 0
       shp.Top = 65
       shp.Height = 60
       shp.Width = 125

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    pptapp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide 14

    GM.Copy

    Set rng = sld(14).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPaste)
    Set shp = rng(1)

       shp.Left = 0
       shp.Top = 65
       shp.Height = 60
       shp.Width = 125

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    pptapp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide 15

    RPE.Copy

    Set rng = sld(15).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPaste)
    Set shp = rng(1)

       shp.Left = 0
       shp.Top = 65
       shp.Height = 60
       shp.Width = 125

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    pptapp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide 16

    SPE.Copy

    Set rng = sld(16).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPaste)
    Set shp = rng(1)

       shp.Left = 0
       shp.Top = 65
       shp.Height = 60
       shp.Width = 125

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    pptapp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide 17

    BHC.Copy

    Set rng = sld(17).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPaste)
    Set shp = rng(1)

       shp.Left = 0
       shp.Top = 65
       shp.Height = 60
       shp.Width = 125

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    pptapp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide 18

    SU.Copy

    Set rng = sld(18).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPaste)
    Set shp = rng(1)

       shp.Left = 0
       shp.Top = 65
       shp.Height = 60
       shp.Width = 125

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    pptapp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide 19

    OPAS.Copy

    Set rng = sld(19).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPaste)
    Set shp = rng(1)

       shp.Left = 0
       shp.Top = 65
       shp.Height = 60
       shp.Width = 125

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    pptapp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide 20

    DDC.Copy

    Set rng = sld(20).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPaste)
    Set shp = rng(1)

       shp.Left = 0
       shp.Top = 65
       shp.Height = 60
       shp.Width = 125

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    pptapp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide 21

    A.Copy

    Set rng = sld(21).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPaste)
    Set shp = rng(1)

       shp.Left = 0
       shp.Top = 65
       shp.Height = 60
       shp.Width = 125

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    pptapp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide 22

    TTP.Copy

    Set rng = sld(22).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPaste)
    Set shp = rng(1)

       shp.Left = 0
       shp.Top = 65
       shp.Height = 60
       shp.Width = 125

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Set sld = Nothing
    Set wholeppt = Nothing
    Set pptapp = Nothing
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set shp = Nothing
End Sub
```

It sometimes run successfully but most of the times come up with the following error:

> Run-time Error '-2147188160 (80048240)':
>   Shapes.PasteSpecial : Invalid Request.
>   Clipboard is empty or contains data which may not be pasted here.

Please help me remove the error as this is office work.

Comment: Well, what line do you get the error on? What kind of data is it trying to paste when the error happens?

Comment: I/O operations, like using the clipboard, and opening and saving files, run more slowly than VBA.  You have to slow down your code using Sleep or DoEvents. There are many code examples online, just Google those two methods.

Comment: josh eller: Error randomly come on the lines of this format (PasteSpecial):-
rng = sld(12).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPaste)
The data format is excel table

Comment: John Korchok: Thanks. Will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had that same issue, this is the code that's working for me. It has an extra DoEvents command (to slow it down) and an extra catch to try a second time in case the first fails. That combined works for me.

Cheers,
Koen

```
rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
DoEvents
Set Shp1 = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set Shp1 = PPslide.Shapes.Paste
On Error GoTo 0
If Not Shp1 Is Nothing Then
    'OK
    Debug.Print XlsNm & "-OK"
Else
    Debug.Print XlsNm & "-ERROR"
    rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
    DoEvents
    Set Shp1 = PPslide.Shapes.Paste
End If
'Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Hey thanks Koen. It seems to work as of now. No error !!

Comment: Cool, can you mark it as the correct answer, that helps other people when they are looking for it.